# Navbar menu not collapsing in each page

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using Boostrap and my navigation menu is collapsing well in my index.html but not in my second page. I use exactly the same code for the header in both pages. Where does it come from ?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light justify-content-between">
      <h1 class="navbar-brand top-title">
        <img src="img/title-logo.svg" alt="" style="width: 30px" /> Title
      </h1>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarMenu"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Example</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Example</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Example</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Example</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Bootstrap link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Scripts

```
 <script src="/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are the two templates within the same folder?

Comment: Thank you Parzival. You solved the problem. I just put the templates in different folder and it works perfectly.